# Holoviz Tutorial Installation: "anaconda-project run jupyter notebook" step fails on Linux + Win 10

Tags: conda, holoviz

**Guessing its a anaconda-project problem**

```
Linux 5.15.0-43-generic: python 3.10.4 , anaconda-project 0.11.0
Windows 10 Pro, 21H2: python 3.10.4, anaconda-project 0.11.0
```

Followed directions at: https://holoviz.org/tutorial/Setup.html

All successful until i get to following step on Linux-

```
$anaconda-project run jupyter notebook
```

keep getting error below, (keep in mind packages being reported as "missing" are verified to exist and have same version used "conda list" to verify, and conda env is activated)-

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - cryptography==37.0.1=py39h9ce1e76_0
  - libedit==3.1.20210910=h7f8727e_0
  - json5==0.9.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - dbus==1.13.18=hb2f20db_0
  - freetype==2.11.0=h70c0345_0
  - gettext==0.21.0=hf68c758_0
  - backports==1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64==2.38=h1181459_1
  - nspr==4.33=h295c915_0
  - libogg==1.3.5=h27cfd23_1

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pyviz/label/dev/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pyviz/label/dev/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nodefaults/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nodefaults/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


missing requirement to run this project: The project needs a Conda environment containing all required packages.
  '/home/khan/Documents/GitHub/holoviz_tutorial/envs/default' doesn't look like it contains a Conda environment yet.
(Use Ctrl+C to quit.)
Value for DATA_1:
```

**Following command on Windows 10-**

```
>conda config --describe channel_priority

(pyvis-testing) C:\Users\alpha\holoviz_tutorial>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 8E4B-11CF

 Directory of C:\Users\alpha\holoviz_tutorial

08/01/2022  10:30 PM    <DIR>          .
08/01/2022  10:30 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/01/2022  10:30 PM               545 .projectignore
08/01/2022  10:30 PM            56,147 anaconda-project-lock.yml
08/01/2022  10:30 PM             1,944 anaconda-project.yml
08/01/2022  10:30 PM    <DIR>          assets
08/01/2022  10:30 PM    <DIR>          data
08/01/2022  10:30 PM        16,792,434 holoviz_tutorial.zip
08/01/2022  10:30 PM    <DIR>          output
08/01/2022  10:30 PM    <DIR>          talks
08/01/2022  10:30 PM    <DIR>          tutorial
               4 File(s)     16,851,070 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  128,561,311,744 bytes free

(pyvis-testing) C:\Users\alpha\holoviz_tutorial>conda install -c pyviz/label/dev jason5

(pyvis-testing) C:\Users\alpha\holoviz_tutorial>anaconda-project run jupyter notebook
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - json5==0.9.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - libogg==1.3.5=h2bbff1b_1
  - backports==1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pyviz/label/dev/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pyviz/label/dev/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nodefaults/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nodefaults/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


missing requirement to run this project: The project needs a Conda environment containing all required packages.
  'C:\Users\alpha\holoviz_tutorial\envs\default' doesn't look like it contains a Conda environment yet.
(Use Ctrl+C to quit.)
Value for DATA_1:
Canceling
```

Comment: Win 10 fail msgs-

Comment: Downgrading to anaconda-project=0.10.2 (prev ver) worked.

Comment: Yes, anaconda-project 0.11 is more strict and needs `defaults` to be specified in the channels list explicitly. Downgrading or adding `defaults` will fix it. We're working on 0.11.1 to restore the previous behavior.

Comment: @JamesA.Bednar I had the same problem despite already using 0.11.1, had to downgrade to get the holoviz tutorial working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading to anaconda-project=0.10.2 (prev ver) solved the issue.